# Shell script variable expansion with escape

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, parameter-passing, parameter-expansion

The following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

nested_func() {
    echo $1
    echo $2
}

func() {
    echo $1
    nested_func $2
}

func 1 "2 '3.1 3.2'"
```

Outputs:

```
1
2
'3.1
```

What I would like to get as output is:

```
1
2
3.1 3.2
```

How do I achieve this output with a single parameter on `func` instead of many?

**EDIT made to address simplifications**

Comment: Have the call be `func 1 '2.1 2.2'`. Don't pass both arguments as one string. It's a flawed requirement.

Comment: Thank you, I just updated the question to address the reason that simplification is not possible.

Comment: You are asking for contradictory requirements that will likely mean you have to manually restack and reparse the arguments. Rethink your design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

nested_func() {
    echo "$1"
    echo "$2"
}

func() {
    nested_func "$@"
}

func 1 '2.1 2.2'
```

`$@` represent all positional parameters given to the function

---

As an alternative you can use this:

```
#!/bin/bash

nested_func() {
    echo "$1"
    echo "$2"
}

func() {
    echo "$1"
    shift
    nested_func "$@"
}

func 1 2 '3.1 3.2'
```

The `shift` keyword allows to skip the first parameter.

You can easily map this if you have 4 parameters...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just updated the question to address the reason that simplification doesn't work.

Comment: Why are the args not still considered a single string argument when passed in a single set of double quotes from `func` to `nested_func`? At first glance I'd've expected it all to be stacked into nested_`func`'s $1, though it works beautifully.

Comment: @AndrasGyomrey: This is the right answer. In `nested_func()` just loop over all the postional arguments as needed. it can be extended for any number of arguments

Comment: The problem is the first parameter is for `func`, whereas the second parameter is a **list** of parameters for `nested_func`. One possibility to use this solution would be to unshift the fixed amount of parameters `func` expects out of `"$@"` to leave the rest for `nested_func`

Answer (score 0):

I have the expected output with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
nested_func() {
    echo $1
    echo $2
}

func() {
    echo $1
    nested_func ${2%% *} "${2#* }"
}

func 1 "2 3.1 3.2"
```

Using [Parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)